# Images do not display consistently between VS and debugging version

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, imagebutton

I have a GridView with three Button columns that are set up with images. When I select my path for the image, using the GUI tool that VS provides, the resulting path is something like `~/Images/myicon.png` and the image displays fine (sometimes) in the VS Design mode. But the images do not display on the running version of the website (using Firefox) because the image locations resolve to `../Images/myicon.png`. I can manually change it to `Images/myicon.png` and it works fine on the website but then not in VS.

How do I get them to behave the same way? These file paths are driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use paths that work in FireFox.  Forget trying to get things to display in design mode, in VS 2005.  Design mode is 2005 is really horrible.

Honestly, design mode can not be relied upon for styling, anyhow, in any version.  It can come close now in VS 2010, but ultimately, it will never be as good as displaying the markup in a browser.